# iOS - How to make a UISlider into a "Scrubber / Seekbar" for video playback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, seekbar, audio-player

I have an instance of `AVAudioPlayer` that plays a local audio file from disk. The playback progress is reflected with a UIProgressView. I'm trying to replace that with a UISlider. To accomplish the task, the slider will:

- move in response to timer event to indicate the current playback position
- respond to manual touch to allow for video scrubbing

I'm not sure how to make the UISlider smart enough to know that **when human touch began, it should stop responding to timer events,** and when the touch is released, it should resume the audio player at a new position and start updating with timer events again.

**Which "Send event" outlets in storyboard would I use to create the behavior 
above?**

Currently I have a generic "value changed" callback.

[image]

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

 if(self.backgroundMusicPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSData* data   = [self.audioFile data];
        self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:data error:&error];

        [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }  
 self.backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = self.slider.value;
 [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Make sure your slider values are appropriate for the playback time. You may have to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is right. To make your code respond to the user adjusting the slider, use the Value Changed event. If you want to be notified that the slider has been touched, use the Touch Down event, or add a gesture recognizer to the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep things simple and just check the `isTracking` property of UISlider which it inherits from UIControl.